# Matching a 7 digit number in the dialplan

Tags: asterisk

im my dialplan, i want to know when a 7 digit number was dialed by the user. But, the dialplan already contains an extension _X. , which would override the seven digit number check.
So,can someone please tell me the right extension to use to match a seven digit number dialed by the user considering the dial plan already contains _X. .

Thank You.

Comment: Were you able to test the answer I have posted below? If so can you give feedback?

Answer (score 3):

If a pattern matches are more than one extension Asterisk will execute the most specific match.

For example given the following 4 extensions in the same context

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _NXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _XXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _867530X,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
```

Asterisk will match them in the following order regardless of where they appear in the context:

```
exten => _867530X,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _NXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _XXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
```

Use "dialplan show extension@context" on the CLI and Asterisk will show you the order in which the matches will execute. For example:

```
*CLI> dialplan show 8675309@default
[ Context 'default' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '_867530X' =>     1. Dial(SIP/foo)                              [pbx_config]
  '_NXXXXXX' =>     1. Dial(SIP/foo)                              [pbx_config]
  '_XXXXXXX' =>     1. Dial(SIP/foo)                              [pbx_config]
  '_X.' =>          1. Dial(SIP/foo)                              [pbx_config]

-= 4 extensions (4 priorities) in 1 context. =-
```

For more information I recommend The Asterisk Wiki

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

Or Asterisk the Definative Guide

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html/asterisk-book.html#asterisk-DP-Basics-SECT-3.6

voip-info tends have a lot of outdated information.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you already have

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _X.,2,Hangup
```

Currently to match the 7 DIGIT Expression
you can do something like this

```
exten => _X.,1,GotoIf( $[${LEN($EXTEN)} = 7] ? dig7)
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/foo)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup
exten => _X.,n(dig7),Dial(ZAP/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Hangup
```

try to avoid conflicts dialplan patterns.

Answer (score 1):

`7` should never override `_X.` because patterns are always checked after non-patterns. See  [voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf+sorting) for more details.

Comment: im not matching for a number 7 but a seven digit number, so i used _XXXXXXX , which i think is a pattern to match a seven digit number, correct me if im wrong. So, _X. which means any digit from 0 to 9 followed by any number of digits would override _XXXXXXX . So, is there a way to prevent that from happening ?